# Bad operand types for binary operator '||' - Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with a project, and I don't quite have the vocabulary to search for the issue I'm having. I think it has to do with syntax of Java regarding chars. Other than the code below, the input is taken as a string above and parsed into a char.

```
switch (accountType)
{
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        // Determine interest based on balance
        if (balance >= 5000)
            interest = balance * .03;
        else
            interest = balance * .01;
        break;

    case 's':
    case 'S':
        interest = balance * .04;
        break;

    default:
        // Catch all for invalid account types
        if (accountType != 'c' || 'C' || 's' || 'S');
            validAccount = false;
}
```

Comment: `||` ors two boolean values.  'C', 's' and 'S' are characters, not booleans.

Comment: If you enter the `default` case we are already sure `accountType` is not c, C, s or S. The whole `if` condition can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
if (accountType != 'c' || 'C' || 's' || 'S');
```

by

```
if (accountType != 'c' || accountType != 'C' || accountType != 's' || accountType != 'S')
```

But to be honest, the condition inside this `if` will always be true. Take for example, if `accountType` is `c`, the first condition will fail but others still pass, and since it's a logical OR, even one `true` is enough for the entire conjunction to return `true`. You can take any other value of `accountType` but it will always return `true`.

Also, you should remove the `;` at the end of `if` statement for the sake of correct semantics. But you may remove the entire `if` as well.

Comment: The logical OR operation with these conditions doesn't make much sense either. if (true) would do the same thing.

Comment: How about providing a correct answer instead of suggesting to introduce a logical bug?

Comment: So you mean to say my answer is wrong ? It may be redundant but clearly it's not wrong. The OP was getting syntax errors and I just suggested what he was doing wrong. @JBNizet

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. The clear intention of the OP is to check that the account type is neither c, nor C, nor s, nor S. Not just to fix a syntax error. Why don't you just fix your answer and explain, instead of complaining about downvotes?

Comment: I edited the answer but you may want to know the difference between "redundant" and "wrong". @JBNizet

Comment: Show me any code sample where using `if (accountType != 'c' || accountType != 'C' || accountType != 's' || accountType != 'S')` is not a bug. It has nothing to do with redundancy. This is equivalent to `if (true)`, and thus can't possibly be correct code.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using the last `if` condition?

I think it is unnecessary. All invalid accounts will fall to the default block automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `accountType` every time for comparision:

```
if(accountType != 'c' || accountType != 'C' || accountType != 's' || accountType != 'S'){

    //your code...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24
"Each operand of the conditional-or operator must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs."

`char` is not `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Too many or's hurting my head... Just use a string that contains what you want and see if the character is contained within it like so

```
String chars = "cCsS";
if(!chars.contains(accountType + ""))
    validAccount = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

While comparing, each time you have to compare against the variable:

```
        if (accountType !='c'|| accountType !='C' || accountType != 's' || accountType !='S')
              validAccount = false;
```

Replace your code with above one.

Note: Remove the `;` at the end.

As mentioned in the comments, since it reaches the default case, you can assume it's a invalid account. So in your switch case

```
  default:
     validAccount = false
```

will suffice...

Comment: Might as well use if (true)